# How can I enable the nautilus feature that on Shift+Right-Click I get an extra menu entry that says “open with“?

Tags: nautilus

I know it was there in previous versions. I often want to open things with gedit. Maybe there's a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option was renamed to **Open With Other Application** and the old behavior of having to SHIFT+RIGHT CLICK was removed since this was an option many users wanted to have by default.

So since 11.10 you only need to right click any folder or file and the option will appear.

I uploaded an image so you can see the new name.

[image]

Comment: I must have been blind :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't hold the shift button while right clicking? Simply right clicking on a file gives me an "Open with" submenu with other programs which support the file's MIME type.